# Passing a list of lists as a parameter to a select (x,y) in clause

Tags: python, mysql, list, sqlalchemy

I have a list of lists that I'm trying to query using the (x,y) IN clause in MySQL via Python. The list is like the below:

```
list = [(item, item), (item, item) ...]
```

and query

```
cursor.execute("select * from table where (x,y) in {}", tuple(list))
```

This is giving me `TypeError: not all arguments converted during string formatting`. What is the correct way of passing the list of lists as a parameter to the select query?

Comment: First of all, NEVER use format strings for database queries where you do not absolutely trust the source of the data. Doing this opens you up to all kinds of SQL injection attacks. Any decent database library in any programming language will have support for proper input sanitation. Second, please include a schema of your database so we can better see what it is you're trying to achieve. Finally, a reference to the Python SQL library you are using would be useful too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here are a few ways you could do this.

If you need to execute from the cursor directly, then this approach works.  You need to manually create the placeholders to match the length of `items`, which is not ideal.  I found this worked when the engine connected using `pymysql` or `MySQLdb`, but not `mysql.connector`.

```py
items = [(1, 2), (12, 10)]

dbapi_conn = engine.raw_connection()
cursor = dbapi_conn.cursor()

cursor.execute("SELECT * FROM username WHERE (user_id, batch_id) IN (%s, %s)",
               items)
res = cursor.fetchall()
for row in res:
    print(row)
print()
dbapi_conn.close()
```

If a raw connection method is not a requirement, this is how you might execute a raw SQL query in SQLAlchemy 1.4+.  Here  we can [expand](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/14/core/sqlelement.html?highlight=expanding#sqlalchemy.sql.expression.bindparam.params.expanding) the bind parameters to handle a variable number of values.This approach also does not work with `mysql.connector`.

```py
with engine.connect() as conn:

    query = sa.text("""SELECT * FROM username WHERE (user_id, batch_id) IN :values""")
    query = query.bindparams(sa.bindparam('values', expanding=True))
    res = conn.execute(query, {'values': items})

    for row in res:
        print(row)
    print()
```

Finally, this approach is pure SQLAlchemy, using the [tuple_()](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/14/core/operators.html#tuple-in-expressions) construct.  It does not require any special handling for values placeholders, but the `tuple_` must be configured. This method is the most portable: it worked with all three connectors that I tried.

```py
metadata = sa.MetaData()
username = sa.Table('username', metadata, autoload_with=engine)

tup = sa.tuple_(sa.column('user_id', sa.Integer), 
                sa.column('batch_id', sa.Integer))

stmt = sa.select(username).where(tup.in_(items))

with engine.connect() as conn:
    res = conn.execute(stmt)
    for row in res:
        print(row)
    print()
```

All of these methods delegate escaping of values to the DBAPI connector to mitigate SQL injections.

Comment: Thank you. Used the first method. Just added extra parenthesis "IN ((%s, %s))". It works perfectly.

Comment: I've edited the answer to show how the second method can be used without having to manually set the number of values placeholders.